# Getting error when trying to use imported mongoose model in api

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I m trying to make a backend server with mongodb and expressjs for my application.

I have 3 collections for my database that I made in 3 separate js files in folder models

collection 1 : report

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const sceSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    date:String,
    name :String,  
});


module.exports=mongoose.model('report',sceSchema);


module.exports.sceSchema=sceSchema;
```

collection 2 : test

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const sceSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    tag:String,
    status:String,
    refimages:Array,
    testimages:Array,
    testresults:Array
})
exports=mongoose.model('Test',sceSchema);


module.exports.sceSchema=sceSchema;
```

collection 3 : result

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const sceSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    pass:Number,
    fail:Number,
    skip:Number,
    date:String
})

module.exports=mongoose.model('result',sceSchema);

module.exports.sceSchema=sceSchema;
```

When I require the 3 models in my controller and code the api, only the report model is working fine when I test it with postman but the other 2 models are giving me this error `sce test is not a function`  or `sceresult is not a function` I'm kinda lost

this is how i call the models in my controller

```
const scemodel= require('../models/sceModel');
const scetest=require('../models/sceModelTest');
const sceresult=require('../models/sceModelresult');
```

example

```
//this works fine
getall:function(req,res){
        scemodel.find({}).exec(function(err,report){
            if(err){
                res.json({message:'error',status:500,data:null})
            }
            else{
                res.json({message:'report in system',status:200,data:report})
            }
        })
    }
//here i get error scetest.find is not a function
getall:function(req,res){
        scetest.find({}).exec(function(err,report){
            if(err){
                res.json({message:'error',status:500,data:null})
            }
            else{
                res.json({message:'report in system',status:200,data:report})
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: why are you using exports twice in  all your collection schema . i dont think you need ```module.exports.sceSchema=sceSchema;``` line , also in collection test you have just written exports its should be module.exports

Comment: yeah figured it out . it was a stupid error of mine